# Binary Search tree in C and build a linked list for duplicate keys

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

```
typedef struct Node{
char Name[100];
char Value[2000];
struct Node *Same;
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
}yelp;

//more codes

//this is what I used to search the key within the BST
void search(yelp *root, char* key, char* OP_filename) {
yelp *current;
current = root;
int steps = 0, count= 0;
FILE *outputFile;
outputFile= fopen(OP_filename,"a");
while (current != NULL) {
   if (strcmp(current->Name,key)==0) {
      count++;
      current = current->Same;
      fprintf(outputFile,"%s --> %s\n", current->Name, current->Value );

   }
   if (strcmp(key,current->Name)<0){
      current = current->left;
   }
   if(strcmp(key,current->Name)>0){
      current = current->right;
   }
   steps++;
}
if(count ==0){
    fprintf(outputFile,"%s --> NOTFOUND\n",key);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s --> NOTFOUND \n",key);
}
else{
fprintf(stdout,"%s --> %d \n",key,steps);`enter code here`

}
fclose(outputFile);
}
```

I write this search method, but it crashed all the time, and I am not capable to find the logical issue. It supposed to build a bst and a linked list for items with same key .plz help me find the problem. I may not explain my problem clearly due to my bad english skills, plz ask me the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: 2nd `if` and 3rd `if` of `strcmp` should be the `else if`.

Comment: `fprintf(outputFile,"%s --> %s\n", current->Name, current->Value );` : `current` might `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the actual implementation of the tree itself is flawless!

Implementing the hints from the commenters and adding some necessary checks gives:

```
void search(yelp * root, char *key, char *OP_filename)
{
  yelp *current;
  int steps = 0, count = 0;
  FILE *outputFile;

  // might fail (most likely reason "too many open files")
  outputFile = fopen(OP_filename, "a");
  if (outputFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failure to open file\n");
    return;
  }

  // early out (not abs. necessary, of course)
  if (root == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "root is NULL\n");
    fprintf(outputFile, "%s --> NOTFOUND\n", key);
    fclose(outputFile);
    return;
  }

  current = root;

  while (current != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(current->Name, key) == 0) {
      count++;
      // exchanged lines; see BLUEPIXY's comment for the reason
      fprintf(outputFile, "%s --> %s\n", current->Name, current->Value);
      current = current->Same;
    } else if (strcmp(key, current->Name) < 0) {
      current = current->left;
    } else if (strcmp(key, current->Name) > 0) {
      current = current->right;
    }
    steps++;
  }
  if (count == 0) {
    fprintf(outputFile, "%s --> NOTFOUND\n", key);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s --> NOTFOUND \n", key);
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s --> %d \n", key, steps);
  }
  fclose(outputFile);
}
```